# Concatenating 2 videos with ffmpeg using ffmpy

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpy

I am trying to concatenate 2 videos but my `ffmpeg` command must be wrong. The output is only the second video `video2.avi`.

```
from ffmpy import FFmpeg
ff = FFmpeg(inputs={'video1.avi': None, 'video2.avi': None}, outputs={'output.avi': None })
ff.cmd
'ffmpeg -f concat -i video1.avi -i video2.avi output.avi'
ff.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to use python library instead of that use shell command

```
ffmpeg -i video1.avi -vcodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -acodec copy part1.ts
ffmpeg -i video2.avi -vcodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -acodec copy part2.ts
cat part1.ts part2.ts > parts.ts
ffmpeg -y -i parts.ts -acodec copy -ar 44100 -ab 96k -coder ac -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb output.avi
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain what these lines do? I tried this solution, but it's not working.